# Is it feasible to extract persons associated to named entity organizations?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy, text-extraction

I am new to text extraction and I would like to extract company names from a text and people associated to the company. I'm thinking of using Spacy to extract these individual parts but I'm not sure whether I'll be able to find the associations, since multiple companies and people will be mentioned within the same text. For example, from the following text:

*Wozniak left Apple in 1983 due to a diminishing interest in the day-to-day running of Apple Computers. Jobs then hired PepsiCo's John Sculley to be president. However, this move backfired and after much controversy with Sculley, Jobs left in 1985 and went on to new and bigger things. He founded his own company NeXT Software and he also bought Pixar from George Lucas*

I would like to pull out companies and people to make the associations (at the very least):
Apple - Wozniak,
PepsiCo - John Sculley, 
Jobs - NeXT Software, Pixar - George Lucas.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how insidious your data are. I would start first with a heuristic using Spacy and match PERS entities with the closest ORG entity. This might get already good results.

If this does not work good enough. I would recommend manually fixing outputs of this algorithm and try to train a classifier using BERT (with the [`transformers`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) package, it is easier than you might think). But for that, you would need several hundreds of annotated pairs.

Comment: And I would just like to add, when you're training a model for this, definitely consider using the dependency parse for grammatical relations between entities: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#pos-tagging